# Difference between 決{き}める and 決{けっ}する?

Tags: word-choice, words

I'm reading a text that has the word 決{けっ}する, and so far I've only seen 決{き}める to mean "decide". I've searched a few dictionaries and couldn't find the difference between the two. Is there a difference or nuance I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**決める**

- a basic word that everyone knows
- basically a weak and casual word like "make a choice", but can also represent stronger decisions (like "make up one's mind"); for authoritative decisions we usually choose other words

  > ピカチュウ！　君に決めた！
  >   *I choose you! Pikachu!*
- **transitive**; the intransitive counterpart is 決まる "be decided"

**決する**

- a big, bookish word that wouldn't be uttered by a child
- means to make a conclusive settlement (usually, of *yes-and-no* or *either-or*) through the decision
- transitive **or** intransitive

  > 運命を決する *(it) determines the fate*
  >   運命が決する *the fate will be determined*

Answer (score 3):

決する mainly appears in some set phrases such as 勝負を決する, [雌雄を決する](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%9B%8C%E9%9B%84%E3%82%92%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B), [意を決する](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%84%8F%E3%82%92%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B). 決する can be used in legal or judicatory contexts, too, although it sounds more stiff than 決める. [けっして](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) with a negative expression means "never", but it's probably better to regard this as a distinct adverb.

Except for these, using 決する instead of 決める would sound fairly literary or even funny. Don't say something like 明日どこに遊びに行くか決する, for instance.